# Can I move all Pokemon at once?

Tags: pokemon-bank

I want to restart my game but with about 500 Pokemon and most of them bred to have perfect IVs I don't really want to lose them. So I bought a 1 Year License for Pokemon Bank to "save everything".

My problem now is: It takes forever to move every single pokemon by hand. Is there some way to upload all boxes and if not: Can I speed up the process somehow?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can press start to select more Pokemon at once.

- The red arrow is the default cursor, with a pop-menu every click.
- The blue arrow let's you move a Pokemon instantly (without the pop-up menu).
- The green arrow lets you select more Pokemon (inside a box). In that way you can transfer up to one box in one go.

So you cannot select all boxes at once, but this is as fast as it'll go at the moment.

Note, this also applies for the in-game computer, not only for the Pokemon Bank.

Comment: Yep this is the only way to do it best I can tell. Be glad you're not moving from gen 5, where not only can you only move one box at a time, you can only move Box 1, and you have to swap between 3 games/apps each box to move it completely. Fun

Comment: Well, I wish this question existed a couple weeks back.

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing? I know of the arrow color (red/blue/green) that you can switch. Red selects single Pokémon and opens the menu, blue selects single Pokémon and immediately picks them up for moving, green selects a range of Pokémon, which can be used to select an entire box at once, but still requires somewhat more than "press start to transfer box 1 in one go". Is this green arrow what you mean in this answer? If so, you might want to clarify a little.

Comment: @scenia Sorry for the late reply. I altered the answer a bit, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Yes, much better :)